# coblogin failing with error "The cache CobrandCache32610008380 is not initialized."

Tags: yodlee

I am Following HTTP POST for `coblogin` API yields a `"The cache CobrandCache32610008380 is not initialized."`

error.

```
curl --data "cobrandLogin=xxx&cobrandPassword=fff" <base url /authenticate/coblogin>
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a Yl. issue. They fixed it.